# Is Partial Index a good Idea for a boolean column that is almost all false?

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have a table: **Parent** that has many **Children** (other table where every child row has a **parent_id**).

So I had the DB index for **children table** on **parent_id**. Which worked well, since I was fetching a specific parent's children all the time..

Now I introduced the `:disabled` boolean column on children table. 
And most times I will fetch only the **enabled children** (disabled = false).

Is it smart to add a partial index like this, since this is the query I'm using the most?

`CREATE INDEX index_for_parent_and_enabled ON children USING btree (parent_id, disabled) WHERE (disabled = false)`

Or since there are very few disabled children, is it better to keep the index only on the **parent_id** column?

Obs: I'm using postgres

I'd really appreciate any comments on this. :)

Comment: If most records are disabled, and you typically fetch enabled records, then an index on disabled would definitely help in cases where you do not specify the parent ID.  In fact, it may make sense (depending on your application) to just return all enabled records and deal with them that way.  I would say do it as a separate index, though, and not added to the existing one for parent.

Comment: I hear you @Hambone. In my app It doesn't make sense to fetch all the children without specifying the parent. In this case, does the compound index make sense?

Comment: I am a mere mortal in the world of databases, and I am rethinking my opinion as I type.  I would *think* a compound index on disabled, parent_id (backwards from what you listed) would potentially be beneficial since the disabled = false is so highly selective.  Do you have sufficient data to do benchmarks?  I'm anxious to see what expert advice weighs in on this -- I can see it being good to know.  It's a good question.

Comment: If parent_id is a FK to the parents PK (I expect it is) you'll need the index anyway (to accomodate cascading, etc) Adding an extra conditional index could help this particular query, though.

Comment: @Hambone thats a good idea! I'll try it out this way because it makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @joop thanks, I'll make a big database and try to bechmark it. I just needed some approval to see if it was worth the effort. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a foreign key on `child(parent_id)`, it is advisable to have an index on the column so that operations on the parent table don't have to scan the complete child table.

If you usually query for

```
... WHERE parent_id = $1 AND NOT disabled
```

and only few records are `NOT disabled`, it could be good to have an additional index

```
CREATE INDEX ON child (parent_id) WHERE NOT disabled;
```

It does not make any sense to have `disabled` in the index, since the condition is already in the WHERE expression. That would only inflate the index.

Comment: THANKS!!! I get it. So you would have two indexes. One on the parent_id and another one on the same column but with the frequent "where" query, correct?

Comment: Yes. As always, test if the index is used.